XDebug (V3) not stopping on break points using VSCODE + Podman
I first set up my XDebug on my Windows host just to make sure I am able to properly configure it and it worked and I was able to set break points in my code and it was stopped by XDebug.
I then wanted to make it work on my Podman container, so I edited the Dockerfile to use a different client_host: Instead of 127.0.0.1, use host.docker.internal.
XDebug seem to connect properly but it won't stop at the break points, so maybe it's connected to something else?
The output of xdebug_info() shows no errors and that it's successfully connected to host.docker.internal:9003 and the Debugger is active.
This is the Dockerfile:
# Use official PHP image with FPM and CLI
FROM php:8.2-fpm

# Install system dependencies and PHP extensions for Laravel
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    unzip \
    libpq-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql zip mbstring xml

# Install Xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Configure Xdebug
RUN echo "zend_extension=xdebug.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.mode=debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.start_with_request=yes" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_port=9003" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_port=9003" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini  \
    && echo "xdebug.idekey=VSCODE" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini 

# Install Composer globally
COPY --from=composer:2.4 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Set the working directory to /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www

# Copy the Laravel project to the container
COPY . .

# Install Laravel dependencies
RUN composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader

# Set permissions for storage and cache
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/storage /var/www/bootstrap/cache

# Expose port 8000 for Laravel's Artisan serve
EXPOSE 8000

# Start the Laravel development server
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000

And this is how I run the container:
podman run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9003:9003 xdebug

What is happening?
I encountered this question on GitHub where someone suggested to add:
"hostname": "localhost"
"pathMappings": {
"/container/files/path": "${workspaceRoot}"
}

though I am not sure to which section, and what is my /container/files/path: https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/issues/653#issuecomment-919385770
